# Gallery which automatically updates self

Tags: photo-gallery

I am looking for a free solution for a gallery which can automatically update itself by reading a directory and seeing if any new files were uploaded recently.
My ideal usage model: I upload new images with FTP to my site, and the gallery updates seamlessly.

Comment: can't you write simple script and launch it every 2 minutes to check if there are any files created within those 2 minutes? If so, then add new entry to the database. You might want to check when the file has been modified as well. This because a little bit more complex if you want to keep track of deleted pictures, but you can fetch all from the database and check if something is missing. This should be rather to do with any language

Comment: By "solution" do you mean something that's packaged to go or are you comfortable writing a bit of JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

One of the simplest options would be the [Single File PHP Gallery](http://sye.dk/sfpg/). Just put it wherever your images are, and you've got a gallery. Sub-directories will be sub-galleries; you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

[Indexhibit](http://www.indexhibit.org/install/) and [Stacey](http://staceyapp.com/) are both static FTP-based CMSes that can be used for simple galleries.